# Why does Loday call the permutohedra "zylchgons"?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, discrete-geometry, terminology, enumerative-combinatorics

Today I was reading Jean-Louis Loday's classic paper, ["Realization of the Stasheff polytope"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212126), in which he produces a simple and very pretty realization of the associahedra as convex polytopes. He introduces the permutohedra like so:

> > Let us recall the definition of the *permutohedron* (alias zylchgon).

I had not heard this alternate name for permutohedra before, and tried to figure out the origin, but couldn't find anything. Sadly, Loday is no longer alive, so I can't ask him. Does anyone know the origin of "zylchgon"?

Comment: This is almost assuredly not the reason, but: the Chow polytope of a 0-dimensional variety (i.e., a set of points) is a Minkowski sum of standard simplices, i.e., a generalized permutohedron. So possibly 0-dimensional = "zilch"?

Comment: Well, Loday's paper is from 2002, and weren't generalized permutohedra invented in 2005 in "Permutohedra, associahedra, and beyond"?

Comment: As I said, almost assuredly not the reason :)

Comment: But the Gelfand Kapranov Zelevinsky textbook does focus on the permutohedron at various points.

Comment: Aha: it seems to have originated in section 6 of Carlsson and Milgram's chapter, "Stable homotopy and iterated loop spaces", https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/carlmilg.pdf . "We now introduce a family of combinatorial cells which do just this, the Zilchgons,
(also called permutahedra by combinatorialists), $C(n)$." I'm still not sure where the "zilchgon" terminology comes from.

Comment: Zilch originates with a German surname, according to Wiktionary. Is there a Dr Zilch?

Comment: in physics the ["zilch current"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilch_(electromagnetism)) is a concept from electromagnetism, so called because it has "zilch" (zero) physical significance; the name originated in a 1964 paper (as discussed [here](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Electrodynamics/Class%20Notes/Chapter%203.pdf) on page 241) --- who knows, it may have inspired Milgram...

Comment: incidentally, the first instance of "zilchgon" I have found is a 1974 [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27293816_Unstable_Homotopy_from_the_Stable_Point_of_View) by Milgram, _Unstable Homotopy from the Stable Point of View_ . Milgram cites an earlier 1966 paper as the origin of the concept, but I did not find the name there.

Comment: Hi Nate! Have you considered emailing Gunnar? Sometimes he writes back, and he's as likely to know the answer as anyone else: http://math.stanford.edu/~gunnar/

Comment: @ViditNanda good idea! I'll email him now.

Comment: @ViditNanda Gunnar Carlsson doesn't know and the email I sent to R.J. Milgram bounced back :(